# Selective apt-get failure using Docker

Tags: apt-get, docker-build

I prepared and tested a dockerfile before sending it to a client, on whose machine, the build process is running into apt-get errors. 
Here is a [image: screenshot] of some of the package download failures.

It doesn't seem to be a proxy issue since most packages, and some wgets, are working fine. I'm not getting any such errors on my own machine, so I'm at a loss as to how to go about debugging the problem. Any leads? 
I am particularly curious what the 400 bad request error indicates. Does it have something to do with the 404 leading up to it?

EDIT: Here is a link to the [Dockerfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwp1m6whoswyqw7/Dockerfile?dl=0).

Comment: Could you attach the dockerfile to the issue so ppl try to run it themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Had this happen to a co-worker. The only thing we change was

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install ...
```

TO

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y
```

I tried all sorts of things, but this was the only thing that worked for me.